# Pandas - Write multiple dataframes to single excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 45 columns and 1000 rows. My requirement is to create a single excel sheet with the top 2 values of each column and their percentages (suppose col 1 has the value 'python' present 500 times in it, the percentage should be 50)

I used:

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx')
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from table limit 1000', <db connection sring>)
    column_list = df.columns.tolist()
    df.fillna("NULL", inplace = True)
    for obj in column_list:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[obj].value_counts().nlargest(2)).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=obj
writer.save()
```

This writes the output in separate excel tabs of the same document. I need them in a single sheet in the below format:

```
Column Name          Value         Percentage
col1                 abc           50
col1                 def           30
col2                 123           40
col2                 456           30
```

....

Let me know any other functions as well to get to this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out to me is that you are changing the sheet name each time, by saying `sheet_name=obj` If you get rid of that, that alone might fix your problem.

If not, I would suggest concatenating the results into one large DataFrame and then writing that DataFrame to Excel.

```
for obj in column_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame(df[obj].value_counts().nlargest(2))
    if df_master is None:
        df_master = df
    else:
        df_master = pd.concat([df_master,df])
df_master.to_excel("abc.xlsx")
```

Here's more information on stacking/concatenating dataframes in Pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Thanks @user2993886    This worked. I had to initialize the df_master as an empty dataframe before the loop. Also I suggest to give sort = True while doing the concat. It will preserve the order of the loop in the excel....